# Changing the userform caption when a page on the multipage is selected

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on creating a userform to input data into excel which I can do easily. I'm not new to vba tho' but I have an issue

I've been trying to write a code to change the caption on the userform when I select a page on the userform and I'm using a multipage.

This is my code below

```
Private Sub MultiPage1_Change()

ComboBox1.SetFocus
If Page2.Enabled = True Then
    UserForm2.Caption = "weekly report format for new service and separate meter installation"
End If

End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

In general UserForms are fun and you should play a bit with yours to find what you are looking for. E.g., here is a small example, changing the caption of the form, based on the ActiveSheet name.

In a module write this:

```
Option Explicit    
Public Sub ShowForm()

    UserForm1.Show vbModeless

End Sub
```

Then create a UserForm, named `UserForm1` and write the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Click()
    Me.Caption = ActiveSheet.Name
End Sub
```

Run `ShowForm`. Click on the form. The caption is changed. Then change the activesheet and click on the form again. Caption is changed again. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask the MultiPage which tab is active and act on that, E.g:

```
Private Sub MultiPage_Change()
    Dim title As String

    Select Case MultiPage1.SelectedItem.Index '// or select on .Name
        Case 0: title = "First page selected"
        Case 1: title = "Second page selected"
        Case 2: title = "Third page selected"
    End Select

    Me.Caption = title
End Sub
```